# How to make two JButtons do separate actions

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

Everytime I press cancel or save on the UI it always executes both of the buttons. I've tried countless ways to make it listen to the if statements in the actionperformed block, but it seems to ignore it. I need it so that if I click save it only executes onSave() and cancel for onCancel(). Thanks for your time

```
public class EditTagPanel extends AbstractTagPanel implements ActionListener {

TagPanelEventListener tagPanelEventListener;
JButton save;
JButton cancel;


public EditTagPanel(ID3v1 id3v1Tag) {
super(id3v1Tag);

}

@Override
protected void configureActionFields() {
JPanel editOptionsPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
save = new JButton("Save");
save.addActionListener(this);
editOptionsPanel.add(save);
cancel = new JButton("Cancel");

cancel.addActionListener(this);
editOptionsPanel.add(cancel);
this.add(editOptionsPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
}

public void addTagPanelEventListener(TagPanelEventListener tagPanelEvent) {

this.tagPanelEventListener = tagPanelEvent;


}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

if (e.getSource().equals(save));
{
tagPanelEventListener.onSave(getId3v1Tag());
}

if(e.getSource().equals(cancel));
{
tagPanelEventListener.onCancel();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just remove:

> **;**

after each `if-statment` in your `actionPerformed()` method, like next:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource().equals(save)) {
        tagPanelEventListener.onSave(getId3v1Tag());
    }

    if (e.getSource().equals(cancel)) {
        tagPanelEventListener.onCancel();
    }
}
```